# Get value based on date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the price point of a product based on future pricing.  I can't really do it by Max (Expiration Date) since the price points are different.  And I also can't do a Max(Price) since the high price might be the one expiring or it could be the new one.  My data would look like this:

| Supplier | Product | Price | Effective Date | Expiration Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Supplier 1 | A | 800 | 04-01-2121 | 12-31-2023 |
| Supplier 1 | A | 1000 | 01-01-2121 | 03-31-2023 |
| Supplier 1 | B | 500 | 04-01-2121 | 12-31-2023 |
| Supplier 1 | B | 400 | 01-01-2121 | 03-31-2023 |
| Supplier 2 | D | 200 | 01-01-2121 | 12-31-2023 |
| Supplier 2 | C | 600 | 01-01-2121 | 12-31-2023 |

The result I am trying to get is below:

| Supplier | Product | Price | Effective Date | Expiration Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Supplier 1 | A | 800 | 04-01-2121 | 12-31-2023 |
| Supplier 1 | B | 500 | 04-01-2121 | 12-31-2023 |
| Supplier 2 | D | 200 | 01-01-2121 | 12-31-2023 |
| Supplier 2 | C | 600 | 01-01-2121 | 12-31-2023 |

Any ideas?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If you hover over the SQL tag that you chose, it asks you to specify Which DBMS the question relates to...  SQLite, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc, etc?

Comment: Can't get the logic... How do expiration_date and effective_date play along here?

Comment: Looks like the row with latest expiration date for each product.

Comment: Where does the `Effective Date` `02-01-2121` in the last row of your result set come from?

Comment: Using BigQuery - so standard SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the product information when `expirationdate` is the greatest we can product wise group the rows in descending order of `expirationdate` and find the row with lowest serial number for each product or we can simply use subquery to select the information where `expirationdate`=`max(expirationdate)` within the product group.
First approach will be more efficient. But if your dbms doesn't support row_number() then you can use second approach.

Schema:

> ```
> create table mydata(Supplier varchar(30),Product varchar(30), Price int,EffectiveDate date,   ExpirationDate date);
> insert into mydata values('Supplier 1',   'A',    800 ,'04-01-2121',  '12-31-2023');
> insert into mydata values('Supplier 1',   'A',    1000    ,'01-01-2121',  '03-31-2023');
> insert into mydata values('Supplier 1',   'B',    500 ,'04-01-2121',  '12-31-2023');
> insert into mydata values('Supplier 1',   'B',    400 ,'01-01-2121',  '03-31-2023');
> insert into mydata values('Supplier 2',   'D',    200 ,'01-01-2121',  '12-31-2023');
> insert into mydata values('Supplier 2',   'C',    600 ,'01-01-2121',  '12-31-2023');
> ```

Query#1

> ```
> WITH cte
>  AS (SELECT supplier,
>             product,
>             price,
>             effectivedate,
>             expirationdate,
>             ROW_NUMBER ()
>                 OVER (PARTITION BY product
>                           ORDER BY expirationdate DESC)
>                 rn
>        FROM mydata)
> SELECT supplier,
>        product,
>        price,
>        effectivedate,
>        expirationdate
>   FROM cte
>  WHERE rn = 1
> ```

Output:

> | supplier | product | price | effectivedate | expirationdate |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Supplier 1 | A | 800 | 2121-04-01 | 2023-12-31 |
> | Supplier 1 | B | 500 | 2121-04-01 | 2023-12-31 |
> | Supplier 2 | C | 600 | 2121-01-01 | 2023-12-31 |
> | Supplier 2 | D | 200 | 2121-01-01 | 2023-12-31 |

Query#2 for older version of DBMS:

> ```
> SELECT supplier,
>        product,
>        price,
>        effectivedate,
>        expirationdate
>   FROM mydata m
>  where effectivedate = 
>        (select max(effectivedate) from mydata md where m.product=md.product)
> ```

Output:

> | supplier | product | price | effectivedate | expirationdate |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Supplier 2 | D | 200 | 2121-01-01 | 2023-12-31 |
> | Supplier 2 | C | 600 | 2121-01-01 | 2023-12-31 |
> | Supplier 1 | B | 500 | 2121-04-01 | 2023-12-31 |
> | Supplier 1 | A | 800 | 2121-04-01 | 2023-12-31 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=991b9232682d0b0a91177f2a5cca40ab)*

Comment: Please ignorr bad formatting. I am using mobile to answer. With row_number() you can do it very easily.

Comment: thanks so much for going into detail.  This is worked out great!

Answer (score 0):

It looks you can accomplish what you need with a simple `row_number` by numbering the rows `decending` ordered against your `ExpirationDate` and filtering for the first row in each group.

```
select Supplier, Product, Price, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate from (
  select Supplier, Product, Price, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, row_number() over (partition by Product order by ExpirationDate desc)Seq
  from table
 )t
 where Seq=1
```